# VBA Partial match (Value/String) of cells consecutive

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with partial Match, the idea is to add a comment on each line if there is a match or not with the below row, result should be as on below picture

[image]

my struggle is with the part with Part Match, ex with B4 Value"87032610" and B5 "Payment 87032610", results which I want to have is txt in column C4 and C5 "Part Match"

so far my code :

```
Sub testRes()
Dim i As Integer

i = 2

Do While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").cells(i, 1) <> ""

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").cells(i, 1) Like "*" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").cells(i + 1, 1) Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Yes"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").cells(i + 1, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Yes"

Else
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = "No"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").cells(i + 1, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = "No"

    End If

i = i + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check variable payment texts against invoice number**

It's less time consuming to loop through an array than cells by means of VBA. In order to check for partial findings just change the direction of `Like` comparisons (completed by surrounding wildcards `*`), as the invoice number represents the smaller part than variable payment texts (of commercial clients).

```
Sub testRes()
'[0]get variant 1-based 2-dim data field array
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("B2:B9")            ' << change to wanted range reference
    Dim v
    v = rng.Value
'[1]check invoice number against changing payment texts
    Dim i As Long
    Dim invoice, pmt
    For i = 1 To UBound(v) - 1 Step 2
        invoice = v(i, 1)
        pmt = v(i + 1, 1)
        If invoice = pmt Then
            v(i, 1) = "Yes"
        ElseIf pmt Like "*" & invoice & "*" Then
            v(i, 1) = "Part Match"
        Else
            v(i, 1) = "No"
        End If
        v(i + 1, 1) = v(i, 1)
    
    Next i
'[2]write results
    rng.Offset(0, 1) = v

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for this, I changed your code and it works fine for me, thank you